# Create a filter that returns Array of array of items

Tags: c#, filter, dto

I need to create a filter that sorts items by Manufacturer, Material(WarehouseItemDefinition), Lot Date , Color and Quality.

[image]

So far I have done the filter to return a collection of WarehouseItemDtos.

My warehouseItem class :

```
public class WarehouseItem : AuditEntity<long>
{

    [ForeignKey("WarehouseItemDefinition")]
    public long WarehouseItemDefinitionId { get; set; }

    public virtual WarehouseItemDefinition WarehouseItemDefinition { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Quality")]
    public long QualityId { get; set; }

    public virtual Quality Quality { get; set; }

    public DateTime LotDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsWastage { get; set; }

    [DoNotMap]
    public int Width { get; set; }

    [DoNotMap]
    public int Height { get; set; }

    [DoNotMap]
    public int Length { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Barcode { get => $"6{Id:D7}"; }

    public virtual List<WarehouseSubItem> Parts { get; set; }
}
```

My warehouseitemdto:

```
public class WarehouseItemDto : IEntityDto<long>
{

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long ManufacturerId { get; set; }

    public long WarehouseItemDefinitionId { get; set; }

    public DateTime LotDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsWastage { get; set; }

    public List<int> Width { get; set; } = new List<int>();

    public List<int> Height { get; set; } = new List<int>();

    public List<int> Length { get; set; } = new List<int>();

    public long Quality { get; set; }
}
```

FilterDto:

```
public class WarehouseItemFilterDto
{

    public long? ManufacturerId { get; set; }

    public string ManufacturerName { get; set; }

    public long? WarehouseItemDefinitionId { get; set; }

    public string WarehouseItemDefinitionName { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }

    public long? QualityId { get; set; }

    public DateTime LotDate { get; set; }

}
```

and my filter method:

```
  public IEnumerable<WarehouseItemDto> GetAllFiltered(WarehouseItemFilterDto filterDto)
        {
            var list = this.repository.GetAll();
            if (filterDto.ManufacturerName != null)
            {
                list = list.Where(l => l.WarehouseItemDefinition.Manufacturer.Name == filterDto.ManufacturerName);
            }
            if (filterDto.ManufacturerId != null)
            {
                list = list.Where(l => l.WarehouseItemDefinition.Manufacturer.Id == filterDto.ManufacturerId);
            }
            if (filterDto.WarehouseItemDefinitionName != null)
            {
                list = list.Where(l => l.WarehouseItemDefinition.Name == filterDto.WarehouseItemDefinitionName);
            }

            if (filterDto.WarehouseItemDefinitionId != null)
            {
                list = list.Where(l => l.WarehouseItemDefinitionId == filterDto.WarehouseItemDefinitionId);
            }

            if (filterDto.Color != null)
            {
                list = list.Where(l => l.WarehouseItemDefinition.Color.ToString() == filterDto.Color);
            }

            if (filterDto.QualityId != null)
            {
                list = list.Where(l => l.QualityId == filterDto.QualityId);
            }

            if (filterDto.LotDate != default)
            {
                list = list.Where(l => l.LotDate.CompareTo(filterDto.LotDate) > 0);
            }
            var result = list.Select(m => mapper.Map<WarehouseItemDto>(m));

return result;

        }
```

I need to return an Array of Manufacturers which contains an Array of WhItemDefinitions that contains an Array of Warehouse items so they can be displayed.

How can I group those Warehouseitems by Manufacturer and then by WHItemDefinition? The DTO only returns ManufacturerId and WhItemDefinitionID, this means I need to have another query to the database to get the names of each of those.

I was thinking of a WarehouseFilterResultDto:
string ManufacturerName, List

WarehouseItemDefinitionFilterDto to have:
string WarehouseItemDefinitionName, List

to fullfill the requirements. My only issue is grouping those.